# How to merge transparent PNG with image using PHP?

Tags: php, image, merge, resize, png

The situation is this: I have a small 50x50 pic. I also have a small 50x50 transparent picture which contains a frame for the 50x50 pic, so I basically want to put the transparent png *on top* of the image and merge those two which would lead to a final third picture that looks something like this: http://img245.imageshack.us/i/50x50n.png

Note: I don't want to do this using HTML only (I achieved this by writing a javascript plugin that put the transparent png on top of the original image).

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can merge the two images together using the PHP GD2 library.

Example:

```
<?php
 # If you don't know the type of image you are using as your originals.
 $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($your_original_image));
 $frame = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($your_frame_image));

 # If you know your originals are of type PNG.
 $image = imagecreatefrompng($your_original_image);
 $frame = imagecreatefrompng($your_frame_image);

 imagecopymerge($image, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50, 100);

 # Save the image to a file
 imagepng($image, '/path/to/save/image.png');

 # Output straight to the browser.
 imagepng($image);
?>
```

Comment: I tried this but my transparent frame just went white on the middle. what's suppose to be the problem.

Comment: you might want to add `header('Content-Type: image/png');` before the last line to ensure the correct MIME type is sent to the browser

Comment: This didn't work for me either, it doesn't seem to save the alpha channel. I also tried adding the alpha blending flag mentioned by the user below.

Answer (score 8):

Add `imagealphablending($frame,true);` before `imagecopymerge()` if you want to keep PNG frame transparancy over the image.

Comment: The image still comes through with the transparent areas white.

Comment: I get the same thing.  Has there been a solution to this yet?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using [ImageMagick :: Composite](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-compositeimage.php). The first user contributed note should be enough to grasp the concept.