# merging two image using PHP?

Tags: php

my problem is that after i used the code in [How to merge transparent PNG with image using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394061/how-to-merge-transparent-png-with-image-using-php) and i merged two images, the first is normal but the second is has a transparent background, when i tested the image it views it like this http://img508.imageshack.us/img508/6658/testingphp.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add imagealphablending($frame,true); before imagecopymerge() if you want to keep png frame transparancy over the image.

-Raf (from the thread you linked, slightly down the page.)

Comment: i tried it before i asked the question, it leaves the `$frame ` image as it is

Comment: Take a look at this perhaps: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagealphablending.php#77085

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code make one **Example.php**

```
<?php
include "GIFEncoder.class.php";

        $frames =array();
        $frames [ 0 ] = "frames/images01.gif";
        $frames [ 1 ] = "frames/images01.gif";
        $framed [ ] = 5;

/*
    GIFEncoder constructor:
    =======================

    image_stream = new GIFEncoder   (
                        URL or Binary data  'Sources'
                        int                 'Delay times'
                        int                 'Animation loops'
                        int                 'Disposal'
                        int                 'Transparent red, green, blue colors'
                        int                 'Source type'
                    );
*/
$gif = new GIFEncoder   (
                        $frames,
                        $framed,
                        0,
                        2,
                        0, 0, 0,
                        "url"
    );
/*
    Possibles outputs:
    ==================

    Output as GIF for browsers :
        - Header ( 'Content-type:image/gif' );
    Output as GIF for browsers with filename:
        - Header ( 'Content-disposition:Attachment;filename=myanimation.gif');
    Output as file to store into a specified file:
        - FWrite ( FOpen ( "myanimation.gif", "wb" ), $gif->GetAnimation ( ) );
*/
Header ( 'Content-type:image/gif' );
echo    $gif->GetAnimation ( );
?>
```

Now create **GIFEncoder.class.php**

```
<?php


Class GIFEncoder {
var $GIF = "GIF89a";        /* GIF header 6 bytes   */
var $VER = "GIFEncoder V2.05";  /* Encoder version      */

var $BUF = Array ( );
var $LOP =  0;
var $DIS =  2;
var $COL = -1;
var $IMG = -1;

var $ERR = Array (
    ERR00=>"Does not supported function for only one image!",
    ERR01=>"Source is not a GIF image!",
    ERR02=>"Unintelligible flag ",
    ERR03=>"Does not make animation from animated GIF source",
);

/*
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::
::  GIFEncoder...
::
*/
function GIFEncoder (
                        $GIF_src, $GIF_dly, $GIF_lop, $GIF_dis,
                        $GIF_red, $GIF_grn, $GIF_blu, $GIF_mod
                    ) {
    if ( ! is_array ( $GIF_src ) && ! is_array ( $GIF_tim ) ) {
        printf  ( "%s: %s", $this->VER, $this->ERR [ 'ERR00' ] );
        exit    ( 0 );
    }
    $this->LOP = ( $GIF_lop > -1 ) ? $GIF_lop : 0;
    $this->DIS = ( $GIF_dis > -1 ) ? ( ( $GIF_dis < 3 ) ? $GIF_dis : 3 ) : 2;
    $this->COL = ( $GIF_red > -1 && $GIF_grn > -1 && $GIF_blu > -1 ) ?
                    ( $GIF_red | ( $GIF_grn << 8 ) | ( $GIF_blu << 16 ) ) : -1;

    for ( $i = 0; $i < count ( $GIF_src ); $i++ ) {
        if ( strToLower ( $GIF_mod ) == "url" ) {
            $this->BUF [ ] = fread ( fopen ( $GIF_src [ $i ], "rb" ), filesize ( $GIF_src [ $i ] ) );
        }
        else if ( strToLower ( $GIF_mod ) == "bin" ) {
            $this->BUF [ ] = $GIF_src [ $i ];
        }
        else {
            printf  ( "%s: %s ( %s )!", $this->VER, $this->ERR [ 'ERR02' ], $GIF_mod );
            exit    ( 0 );
        }
        if ( substr ( $this->BUF [ $i ], 0, 6 ) != "GIF87a" && substr ( $this->BUF [ $i ], 0, 6 ) != "GIF89a" ) {
            printf  ( "%s: %d %s", $this->VER, $i, $this->ERR [ 'ERR01' ] );
            exit    ( 0 );
        }
        for ( $j = ( 13 + 3 * ( 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 ) ) ), $k = TRUE; $k; $j++ ) {
            switch ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { $j } ) {
                case "!":
                    if ( ( substr ( $this->BUF [ $i ], ( $j + 3 ), 8 ) ) == "NETSCAPE" ) {
                        printf  ( "%s: %s ( %s source )!", $this->VER, $this->ERR [ 'ERR03' ], ( $i + 1 ) );
                        exit    ( 0 );
                    }
                    break;
                case ";":
                    $k = FALSE;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    GIFEncoder::GIFAddHeader ( );
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count ( $this->BUF ); $i++ ) {
        GIFEncoder::GIFAddFrames ( $i, $GIF_dly [ $i ] );
    }
    GIFEncoder::GIFAddFooter ( );
}
/*
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::
::  GIFAddHeader...
::
*/
function GIFAddHeader ( ) {
    $cmap = 0;

    if ( ord ( $this->BUF [ 0 ] { 10 } ) & 0x80 ) {
        $cmap = 3 * ( 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ 0 ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 ) );

        $this->GIF .= substr ( $this->BUF [ 0 ], 6, 7       );
        $this->GIF .= substr ( $this->BUF [ 0 ], 13, $cmap  );
        $this->GIF .= "!\377\13NETSCAPE2.0\3\1" . GIFEncoder::GIFWord ( $this->LOP ) . "\0";
    }
}
/*
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::
::  GIFAddFrames...
::
*/
function GIFAddFrames ( $i, $d ) {

    $Locals_str = 13 + 3 * ( 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 ) );

    $Locals_end = strlen ( $this->BUF [ $i ] ) - $Locals_str - 1;
    $Locals_tmp = substr ( $this->BUF [ $i ], $Locals_str, $Locals_end );

    $Global_len = 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ 0  ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 );
    $Locals_len = 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 );

    $Global_rgb = substr ( $this->BUF [ 0  ], 13,
                        3 * ( 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ 0  ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 ) ) );
    $Locals_rgb = substr ( $this->BUF [ $i ], 13,
                        3 * ( 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 ) ) );

    $Locals_ext = "!\xF9\x04" . chr ( ( $this->DIS << 2 ) + 0 ) .
                    chr ( ( $d >> 0 ) & 0xFF ) . chr ( ( $d >> 8 ) & 0xFF ) . "\x0\x0";

    if ( $this->COL > -1 && ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x80 ) {
        for ( $j = 0; $j < ( 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 ) ); $j++ ) {
            if  (
                    ord ( $Locals_rgb { 3 * $j + 0 } ) == ( ( $this->COL >> 16 ) & 0xFF ) &&
                    ord ( $Locals_rgb { 3 * $j + 1 } ) == ( ( $this->COL >>  8 ) & 0xFF ) &&
                    ord ( $Locals_rgb { 3 * $j + 2 } ) == ( ( $this->COL >>  0 ) & 0xFF )
                ) {
                $Locals_ext = "!\xF9\x04" . chr ( ( $this->DIS << 2 ) + 1 ) .
                                chr ( ( $d >> 0 ) & 0xFF ) . chr ( ( $d >> 8 ) & 0xFF ) . chr ( $j ) . "\x0";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    switch ( $Locals_tmp { 0 } ) {
        case "!":
            $Locals_img = substr ( $Locals_tmp, 8, 10 );
            $Locals_tmp = substr ( $Locals_tmp, 18, strlen ( $Locals_tmp ) - 18 );
            break;
        case ",":
            $Locals_img = substr ( $Locals_tmp, 0, 10 );
            $Locals_tmp = substr ( $Locals_tmp, 10, strlen ( $Locals_tmp ) - 10 );
            break;
    }
    if ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x80 && $this->IMG > -1 ) {
        if ( $Global_len == $Locals_len ) {
            if ( GIFEncoder::GIFBlockCompare ( $Global_rgb, $Locals_rgb, $Global_len ) ) {
                $this->GIF .= ( $Locals_ext . $Locals_img . $Locals_tmp );
            }
            else {
                $byte  = ord ( $Locals_img { 9 } );
                $byte |= 0x80;
                $byte &= 0xF8;
                $byte |= ( ord ( $this->BUF [ 0 ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 );
                $Locals_img { 9 } = chr ( $byte );
                $this->GIF .= ( $Locals_ext . $Locals_img . $Locals_rgb . $Locals_tmp );
            }
        }
        else {
            $byte  = ord ( $Locals_img { 9 } );
            $byte |= 0x80;
            $byte &= 0xF8;
            $byte |= ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 );
            $Locals_img { 9 } = chr ( $byte );
            $this->GIF .= ( $Locals_ext . $Locals_img . $Locals_rgb . $Locals_tmp );
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->GIF .= ( $Locals_ext . $Locals_img . $Locals_tmp );
    }
    $this->IMG  = 1;
}
/*
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::
::  GIFAddFooter...
::
*/
function GIFAddFooter ( ) {
    $this->GIF .= ";";
}
/*
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::
::  GIFBlockCompare...
::
*/
function GIFBlockCompare ( $GlobalBlock, $LocalBlock, $Len ) {

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $Len; $i++ ) {
        if  (
                $GlobalBlock { 3 * $i + 0 } != $LocalBlock { 3 * $i + 0 } ||
                $GlobalBlock { 3 * $i + 1 } != $LocalBlock { 3 * $i + 1 } ||
                $GlobalBlock { 3 * $i + 2 } != $LocalBlock { 3 * $i + 2 }
            ) {
                return ( 0 );
        }
    }

    return ( 1 );
}
/*
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::
::  GIFWord...
::
*/
function GIFWord ( $int ) {

    return ( chr ( $int & 0xFF ) . chr ( ( $int >> 8 ) & 0xFF ) );
}
/*
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::
::  GetAnimation...
::
*/
function GetAnimation ( ) {
    return ( $this->GIF );
}
}
?>
```

Place **images01.gif** and **images02.gif** in frames folder beside this two files

Now Run Example.php

You can also download code from her

[Download Link](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3163.html?download=zip)

I have tried this and it works.

with regards

**Wasim**

Answer (score 0):

try with Imagick::compositeImage

Comment: imageick is disabled by my host

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it for 100% same requirements as yours. The definition is self-explanatory.

```
function create_watermarked_image($image,$overlay,$align='right',$valign='bottom',$offset_w=0,$offset_h=0)
{
    if(!in_array($align,array('left','center','right')))
    $align='right';
    if(!in_array($valign,array('top','middle','bottom')))
    $valign='bottom';
    $background=$image;
    // Find base image size
    $iwidth = imagesx($image);
    $iheight = imagesy($image);
    // Turn on alpha blending
    imagealphablending($image, true);
    // Get the size of overlay
    $owidth = imagesx($overlay);
    $oheight = imagesy($overlay);
    //align
    if($align=='left')
    $x = $offset_w;
    elseif($align=='center')
    $x= $iwidth/2 - $owidth/2;
    elseif($align=='right')
    $x=$iwidth - $owidth - $offset_w;
    //valign
    if($valign=='top')
    $y = $offset_h;
    elseif($valign=='middle')
    $y = $iheight/2 - $oheight/2 ;
    elseif($valign=='bottom')
    $y = $iheight - $oheight - $offset_h;
    // Overlay watermark
    imagecopy($image, $overlay, $x, $y, 0, 0, $owidth, $oheight);
    return $image;
}
```

Another useful function to feed above one

```
function create_image_from_file($img,$file_name=false)
{
    if (!file_exists($img))
    return -1;

    if(!$file_name)
    $ext = strtolower(substr($img, strrpos($img, ".") + 1));
    else
    $ext = strtolower(substr($file_name, strrpos($file_name, ".") + 1));

    switch ($ext)
    {
        case 'jpg':
        $img2=imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
        break;
        case 'jpeg':
        $img2=imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
        break;
        case 'png':
        $img2=imagecreatefrompng($img);
        break;
        case 'gif':
        $img2=imagecreatefromgif($img);
        break;
        default:
        return -2;
    }
    if($img2)
    return $img2;
    else
    return -3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work: 
http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/watermark_image