# PHP png image compositing

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to merge transparent PNG with image using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394061/how-to-merge-transparent-png-with-image-using-php)

I am completely lost here, so help would be greatly appreciated.
I am new to PHP image manipulation.

I have two semi-transparent png files, and I would like to overlay one over the other and output the resulting png.

Thanks in advanced.

EDIT:

1. GD, though I can change that if needed.
2. So far I've hacked this together from what I could find on the internet.
   It does not work.

Comment: What library are you using? (e.g. GD, Imagick)

Comment: The solution posted does not work. Perhaps it is my version of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

[imagecopymerge](http://php.net/imagecopymerge) would be the solution

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");

$overlay = imagecreatefrompng("overlay.png");
$overlay_width = imagesx($overlay);
$overlay_height = imagesy($overlay);
$im = imagecreatefrompng("firstimage.png");
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);
$dest_x = 0;
$dest_y = 0;
imagecopymerge($im, $overlay, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $overlay_width, $overlay_height, 100);

imagepng($im);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the resulting image has a black background.

Comment: i just tried that and works perfectly, the images i was testing had transparent background .. the final image still has transparent background .. my php version is 5.2.10 with gd 2.0.34, maybe it's from your php version ..